# Iterating through a dictionary datatype column within an API response

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.9 to parse through an API response where the values of one of the keys (products) is of dict type. I need to loop through the values of the 'product' key.

Example:

```
[{'id': 78456, 'item': '48-20213', 'product': {'id': 21438274735, 'supplier_part_number': '14109', 'color': 'Green’},'stats': None}]
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())

final_df = df[['product']]
```

how can I use final_df to iterate through the values? I'm trying to get the value of 'supplier_part_number'.

Comment: Please provide a sample of df as well as the results of df.info()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  import json
  r = [{'id': 78456, 'item': '48-20213', 'product': {'id': 21438274735,'supplier_part_number': '14109', 'color': 'Green'},'stats': None}]
  print(json.dumps(r[0]['product'],indent = 4))
```

To loop through the dictionary you can do something like this, as it is a nested dictionary you need to use the 'product' key as shown below.

```
  for key, value in r[0]['product'].items():
      print(f"key:{key},value:{value}")
```

Comment: @Alex01 Especially if it worked for you, [*accepting* an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is the way to show gratitude.